# PHP 5.6 on Bash for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, bash, php, windows-10-v1607

Hi there's any repository where I can find the PHP 5.6 version for the bash console for windows?

With:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

I've got installed PHP v5.5

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2017 20:54:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-cli`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode yes, I've installed also

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but this link might be useful https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: @Cyclonecode thanks, with the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` I have been able to install with `sudo apt-get install php5.6`